# Region wise percentage

Tags: oracle, sum

i need to calculate percentage grosssales with regionwise breakup on a particular segment ie Domestic Corp .
My Query is

```
 select    REGION_NAME,  
           round(ratio_to_report(nvl(sum(gross_sales_amt_t),0)) over ()*100) as Gr_Sales_domcorp 
 from      fact_mfdex_segment A 
 JOIN      dim_location B 
 ON        a.branch_code = b.branch_code 
 WHERE     to_date(DATE_SK,'YYYYMMDD') between '01-feb-2016' and '01-mar-2016' 
 AND       week_flag='Y' 
 AND       a.segments = 'Domestic Corp.' 
 group by  REGION_NAME;
```

I need to repeat the same query for HNI,RETAIL ETC. instead of Domestic Corp. rather than writing different query can i use my first query to add other segments. I have tried case statement but not working. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a.segments to the selected columns, remove the "AND a.segments = ..." line, partition ratio_to_report by a.segments, and group by a.segments and REGION_NAME. You may want to change the output column name from Gr_Sales_domcorp to Gr_Sales. Something like this:

```
select     REGION_NAME, a.segments, 
           round(ratio_to_report(nvl(sum(gross_sales_amt_t),0)) 
                   over (partition by a.segments)*100) as Gr_Sales 
 from      fact_mfdex_segment A 
 JOIN      dim_location B 
 ON        a.branch_code = b.branch_code 
 WHERE     to_date(DATE_SK,'YYYYMMDD') between '01-feb-2016' and '01-mar-2016' 
 AND       week_flag='Y'  
 group by  a.segments, REGION_NAME
 order by  a.segments, REGION_NAME
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me :) i just had to add another block above to seperate it into different columns with case statement

Comment: You should be able to get your rows and columns with pivoting. On the other hand, that format sounds more like a REPORTING requirement; easier done using standard reporting tools, whatever is used in your organization. Anyway - glad you got the help you needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just include all the records for required segments by putting them inside "IN" clause and then group by segment also and here you go for expected results.

```
 select    REGION_NAME,  
           round(ratio_to_report(nvl(sum(gross_sales_amt_t),0)) over ()*100) as Gr_Sales_domcorp 
 from      fact_mfdex_segment A 
 JOIN      dim_location B 
 ON        a.branch_code = b.branch_code 
 WHERE     to_date(DATE_SK,'YYYYMMDD') between '01-feb-2016' and '01-mar-2016' 
 AND       week_flag='Y' 
 AND       a.segments IN ( 'Domestic Corp.','HNI','RETAIL') 
 group by  REGION_NAME, a.segments;
```

---

Comment: ?  This will not show a regional breakdown separately for Domestic Corp, separately for HNI, etc. I thought the OP's requirement was clear.

Comment: To be clear: what you are missing is the partition_by clause in ratio_to_report.

Comment: @MaheshChand .Thanks but I want is. Suppose there are 10 regions then I need 4 columns and 10 rows. i,e regionname, gross_domcorp, gross_hni, gross_retail.